# Synchronicity of javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand which parts of javascript are synchronous and which are asynchronous.

My question is, in the following code why does it alert `16384` *before* it alerts `1` when the loop takes waay longer than 1ms ?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7X7F7/)**

```
setTimeout(function () {
    alert(1)
}, 1)

for (i = 0; i < 16384; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 16384; j++) {}
}


alert(j)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript is generally single-threaded. This means that your `setTimeout` callback can't happen until you relinquish control of the thread. Your double `for` loop executes and shows its alert before the `setTimeout` alert is allowed to happen.

Answer (score 4):

The JS engine won't check to see if any functions are waiting for a timeout to finish until the event loop is free.

i.e. It is too busy running your nested for loops to check.

When it has finished running those loops, it checks, discovers that the timeout is overdue and runs it immediately.